# Smarty can't access compiled files in templates_c

Tags: php, smarty

I just installed a cms system but I'm getting the following error:

```
[function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
 /home/postertest/domains/buyuseraccounts.com/public_html/libs/Smarty.class.php 
on line 1283
```

When I check the templates_c file, the requested file is however there:

**%%45^45E^45E480CD%%index.tpl.php**

When i try to access the compiled file directly through the browser, it however gives a 404. When I rename the file (%%45^45E^45E480CD%%index.tpl.php) I can access it. It therefore seems that the error is caused by by Apache.. What should i do?

**UPDATE**

Actually, now that i test it out to another CMS on the same server, it appears there i can't access the files underneath templates_c directly as well. However there, Smarty doesn't cause any error. I tried putting the smarty distribution of the working cms to the non-working but still it gives the same error.

Comment: Did you set permissions correctly? Are you using the right path?

Comment: yeah of course, otherwise i couldn't access the file by renaming it to index.php of course :S

Comment: You might be unwittingly changing permissions by renaming it, if you're using a GUI.

Comment: I progressively renamed it, when it got to index.php, it worked.

Comment: So what are the owner/group/permissions on the containing directory, and newly created files?

Comment: Files: 644
templates_c: 755

Comment: Actually, now that i test it out to another CMS, it appears there i can't access the files directly as well. However there, there's no error. I tried putting the smarty distribution of the working cms to the non-working but still it gives the same error.